# How to get version from package.json in next js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I am trying to get the "version" from the `package.json` is nextjs application.

I have tried `process.env.npm_package_version` like in node application but it's returning `undefined`.

Comment: https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/environment-variables#bundling-environment-variables-for-the-browser

Comment: @juliomalves: I don't think this question should have been closed as a duplicate. There are specifics for nextjs, which are not generally applicable to nodejs. For example, anything involving next.config.js.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `process.env.npm_package_version` only if you installed the package `package_vars` before (see: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/using-npm/scripts#packagejson-vars)

But the simplest way in your case is to import your `package.json` file (which is a mere `.json` file) like this:

```js
const { version } = require('./package.json');
console.log(version);
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked, but for typescript it need to be imported like so `import * as pack from '../../package.json';` and then `const version = pack.version;`

Comment: Sorry, I only read the first tag (which is `javascript`)

Comment: Correction, next.js prefer no recasting, so `import pack from '../../package.json';` It will show warning with re-casting or importing just the version

Answer (score 11):

in `NextJs` you can create a `next.config.js` file and below lines.

```
const { version } = require('./package.json');

module.exports = {
  publicRuntimeConfig: {
    version,
  },
};
```

then when you need the version anywhere in app

```
import getConfig from 'next/config';

const { publicRuntimeConfig } = getConfig();
const version = publicRuntimeConfig?.version
```

for more info read [this](https://martinratinaud.medium.com/how-to-show-your-app-version-in-a-nextjs-application-4deefd73e306) article.

Update 2023/11/23 :
Next js says this feature is deprecated and you better use environment variables for that usage. But you can still do the same thing with `publicRuntimeConfig`. For better explanation see this part of their [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/next-config-js/runtime-configuration).

Here is a "modern" version, which works in next 14, at least:

```
const { version } = require('./package.json');
    
module.exports = {
  env: {
    version
  }
};
```

You can then access `version` in the app code by `process.env.version`

Comment: nextjs.org say this feature is deprecated! [https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/next-config-js/runtime-configuration]

Comment: @MohmmadEbrahimiAval thanks for the heads up. Answer has been updated

Comment: https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/environment-variables#bundling-environment-variables-for-the-browser